# Atom hydrogen kernel issue: Fixing PATH with zsh on macbook pro

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor

I installed hydrogen kernel for Python on Atom using

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

After doing so, I got the following messages

```
WARNING: The script pygmentize is installed in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framewo
rk/Versions/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning,
 use --no-warn-script-location.
  
WARNING: The scripts jupyter, jupyter-migrate and jupyter-troubleshoot are install
ed in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning,
 use --no-warn-script-location.
  
WARNING: The scripts jupyter-kernel, jupyter-kernelspec and jupyter-run are instal
led in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning,
 use --no-warn-script-location.

WARNING: The scripts iptest, iptest3, ipython and ipython3 are installed in '/Libr
ary/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning,
 use --no-warn-script-location.

WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.9 are installed in '/Library/Frameworks/Py
thon.framework/Versions/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning,
 use --no-warn-script-location.
```

How can I fix this issue to avoid problems in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your `.zprofile` or `.zshenv` file:

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: How can I locate the file/s?

Comment: If it's not already in your home directory, you can create it.